# Execute a function from another activity

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to retrieve some data (state) from an activity in order to render it in my home activity. The thing is, I need to execute a function that updates the state before retrieving it. So my question is, how can I call this function from my home page ? Is it possible with react-navigation for example ?

```
        <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('NewCar', {CarName:this.state.CarName})}>
```

The CarName variable is the one I want to retrieve, but it's value resets every time the app is closed, so I need to execute a function from the NewCar activity that sets a value to it.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The question is not very clear.